# sql select count of multiple relationships with left join

Tags: sql

I have  a table for "branches", "orders" and "products. Each order and product are connected to a branch with branch_id. I need an sql statement to get a list of all branches with a field for how many orders and a field for how many products.

This works:

`SELECT  b.*, COUNT(o.id) AS orderCount FROM branches b
            LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.branch_id = b.id) GROUP BY b.id`

but it only gets the amount of orders, not products.
If I change it to add amount of products, the amounts are wrong because it's getting amount of orders * amount of products.

How can I get the amount of both the orders and the products in the same SQL statement?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Something like this should work (on sql server at least - you didn't specify your engine).

```
SELECT 
    b.id
   ,COUNT(distinct o.id) AS orderCount 
   ,COUNT(distinct p.id) AS productCount 
FROM branches b 
LEFT JOIN orders o 
    ON (o.branch_id = b.id)
left join products p
    on p.product_id=b.id)
GROUP BY 
    b.id
```

Answer (score 8):

Please try:

```
select
    *,
    (select COUNT(*) from Orders o where o.branch_id=b.id) OrderCount,
    (select COUNT(*) from Products p where o.branch_id=p.id) ProductCount
From 
    branches b
```

Comment: this solution is more flexible because you can put all your conditions in the same time to get the count of specific items, thanks

Comment: Subqueries like this are a slippery slope. You can make your code very slow very quickly.